# составить SQL запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Достаточно распространенный способ хранения тегов.
Есть две таблицы:
`tags` (хранит теги)
[image: таблица tags]

и `tags_relations` (хранит связи тегов с другими сущностями)
[image: таблица tags_relations]

Каким образом получить 10 самых часто используемых тега и собственно количество использования каждого из них. Т.е. чтобы результирующая таблица включала в себя 2 колонки: название тега и счетчик его использований.
Буду признателен за помощь, пока что более менее сложные запросы вводят в ступор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.name, COUNT(a.tag_id) FROM tags_relations a
LEFT JOIN tags b ON b.id = a.tag_id
GROUP BY a.tag_id
ORDER BY COUNT(a.tag_id) DESC
LIMIT 10
```